# Laravel - Pass more than one variable to a view

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a blog using the Laravel framework. I have 4 sections(carousel slider, the sidebar, and two other sections).

I want to pass the data as follows; recent posts to be displayed in the slider, popular posts in the sidebar, category1(sports) posts in the third section and category2(politics posts) in 4th sections.

How can I pass all those data on a single view??

Comment: where's your code in your `controller` and `blade`? have you tried anything but doesn't work?

Comment: You likely want to use view composers for anything used globally like a sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
return view('view_name')->with(['var1' => $value1,'var2' => $value2]);
```

You can access it later from your view as `$var1` and `$var2`

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this

```
$arr_view_data['var1'] = $value1;
$arr_view_data['var2'] = $value2;
$arr_view_data['var3'] = $value3;

return view('your_viewname_here',$arr_view_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 approaches for this:

1st Approach:

```
 return view('view_name')->with(['var1' => $value1,'var2' => $value2,....]);
```

2nd Approach:

```
return view('view_name',compact('var1','var2',.....));
```

The compact method will get the var1 and var2 automatically and will pass it to the view.